# reactive vue function with setInterval

Tags: vue.js

i want make this function updates evry 1000ms

```
const countDaysLeft = (date) => {
    let dateNow = new Date().getTime();
    let countDate = new Date(date).getTime();
    let dateDiff = countDate - dateNow;
    let days = Math.floor(dateDiff / 1000);
    return days;
};
```

i tried doing this

```
const countDaysLeft = (date) => {
  return setInterval(() => {
    let dateNow = new Date().getTime();
    let countDate = new Date(date).getTime();
    let dateDiff = countDate - dateNow;
    let days = Math.floor(dateDiff / 1000);
    return days;
  }, 1000);
};
```

and here where i'm trying to display it in the page

```
    <div
    class="w-full h-32 p-2 rounded-md text-gray-100 flex flex-col 
    justify-between"
    v-for="countdown in countdownsArray"
    :id="countdown.id"
  >
    <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold">{{ countdown.title }}</h1>
    <h1 class="text-lg font-semibold">
      {{ countDaysLeft(countdown.date) }}
    </h1>
    <h1 class="text-sm text-gray-200">{{ countdown.date }}</h1>
  </div>
```

but it's stil not working, any idea to make my function reactive?

Comment: What does "reactive" means? Please, describe your case

Comment: @EstusFlask the function value only updates when refreshing the page, i want the value to updates every 1000ms without refreshing the page

Comment: How is countDaysLeft used? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You obviously can't return anything from interval function, and returning setInterval is a mistake because it returns an interval that can be cleared, not a value

Comment: @EstusFlask i have an array of object evry object has countdown date i loop the array and countdown for every date and display countdown at the page this is how i use it and how it should works

Comment: The description doesn't contain info on where this function is called. It makes sense for you because you know your own case, but not for the others. See the link above. The question needs MCVE, it's a requirement for code-based questions. Otherwise the question isn't constructive and can be closed

Comment: @EstusFlask i updated the code hop that is clear what i'm trying to do

Comment: Yes, it is. You need to use setInterval in mounted hook to update state property that derives from countdownsArray (e.g. countdownDays that has the same length as countdownsArray) , and clear the interval in unmounted. Basically what the answer shows but you need an array of numbers, not a single number. No need for countDaysLeft in a template, can use it inside setInterval like `countdownDays[i] = countDaysLeft(countdownsArray[i])`. You could still use the original countDaysLeft in a template and just do $forceUpdate every second inside setInterval, but that's a hack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254561/discussion-between-mofarih-dev-and-estus-flask).

Comment: @EstusFlask can you add this to my code?

Answer (score 2):

Use reactivity system of Vue 3. I like writing in `script setup` format.

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

const daysLeft = ref(0)

let intervalId

onMounted(() => {
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    const dateNow = Date.now()
    const countDate = new Date('2024-12-31').getTime()
    const dateDiff = countDate - dateNow
    daysLeft.value = Math.floor(dateDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
  }, 1000)
})

onUnmounted(() => clearInterval(intervalId))
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Days Left: {{ daysLeft }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Pretty straight forward, right?

Comment: i don't have a spefic date to countdown to so i need ``daysLeft`` as a function with `date` paramter so i can loop on array of dates and countdown for every date

Comment: @mofarih-dev The answers are as good as the question is. If the way it works is important to you, you should have been state this. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The actual approach is the same as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76711635/3731501), but based on the recent details, it's an array of values instead of a single value that needs to be calculated.

```
let intervalId;
let daysArray = reactive([]);

onMounted(() => {
  daysArray.length = countdownsArray.length;

  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    countdownsArray.forEach((date, i) => {
      daysArray[i] = countDaysLeft(i);
    });
  }, 1000)
});

onUnmounted(() => {
  clearInterval(intervalId)
});

...

<template>
    <div v-for="(countdown, i) in countdownsArray"
    :id="countdown.id"
  >
    ...
    {{ daysArray[i] }}
    ...
```

The mutation of an array in Vue 2 would additionally require to use `Vue.set`.